# Construct a data structure with special requirements in python

Tags: python, data-structures

Requirements:

1. There is a variable, for example, related_to_dict = 10
2. Construct a key value pair data, for example, special_dict = {0 :
   ref_related_to_dict}
3. When the variable of related_to_dict changed, the value of
   special_dict[0] also changed to the value of related_to_dict
   accordingly.
4. When the value_of special_dict[0], e.g. ref_related_to_dict changed, the
   value of related_to_dict also changed to the value of
   special_dict[0] accordingly.

Is there a way to achieve this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the value in some sort of container.

```
class Ref:
   def __init__(self, v):
        self.val = v
```

And then:

```
related_to_dict = Ref(10)
special_dict = {0: related_to_dict}
```

Then it works as desired:

```
related_to_dict.val = 40
print(special_dict[0].val) # 40
```

Comment: But the 4th requirement isn't satisfied, which is, if the special_dict[0] changed, its related variable should be changed accordingly. So maybe dictionary-like data structure doesn't fit here.

Comment: It is, you just have to change the wrapped value: `special_dict[0].val = 653`. Or in other words, `ref_related_to_dict = special_dict[0]; ref_related_to_dict.val = 653`

Comment: It makes sense, thanks! But If there is some pointer like C programming in Python, then it will be simpler.